# oracle identifier 'ctx_ddl' must be declared - adding a dbms_job

Tags: oracle, indexing, sqlplus, database

I've added an index to my table with the command:
`CREATE INDEX patient_index ON radiology_record(patient_name) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;`

And I'm trying to add a DBMS_JOB which will keep it up to date.
The way I've been running this script is by calling "@myscript.sql" from SQLPLUS

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
   job number; 
begin
   dbms_job.submit(job, 'ctx_ddl.sync_index(''patient_index'');',
                  interval=>'SYSDATE+1/1440');   
   commit;
   dbms_output.put_line('job '||job||'has been submitted.'); 
 end;
 /
```

The resulting error is `PLS-00201: identifier 'CTX_DDL' must be declared`

Through my searching I've found someone with a similar problem and his [solution](http://openacs.org/forums/message-view?message_id=34391) was

> I spent enough time
> debugging this that I thought it
> merited sharing what i learned. It
> turns out that dbms_jobs only inherit
> your schema user's default privileges,
> not any privileges it might inherit
> from roles granted to that user. This
> means that the job will not run with
> the ctxsys privilege that you should
> have granted to your schema user. So
> what does this mean? It means that you
> have to run the job as the ctxsys user

I unfortunately cannot use this to grant myself privileges since yes, this is homework, and I don't have permissions to grant execute on ctx_ddl to myself.

Does anyone have clues as to how I can resolve this issue? Otherwise I will wait until later this week and consult the TA's.
Thanks

Comment: This feature - that privileges granted through roles don't apply in pl/sql - is a standard (and annoying) Oracle feature. You will need to have execute on ctx_ddl granted explicitly to you. You'll find over time that the same applies to other types of objects, notably tables and views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a workaround since the [documentation of `DBMS_JOB`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#i996758) explicitly specifies this restriction:

> You can execute procedures that are owned by the user or for which the user is explicitly granted EXECUTE. However, procedures for which the user is granted the execute privilege through roles cannot be executed.

Comment: For the detailed SQL instruction to grand the `EXECUTE` privilege on `CTXSYS.CTX_DDL` package, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/quicktour.htm => looks like `GRANT EXECUTE ON CTXSYS.CTX_DDL TO myuser;`